# Python-Matching two dataset - One column in one dataset with 'Min_Range/Starting_Point' in the other dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and need some help in matching one dataset with another dataset by range.

I have one master dataset 'df1' with Driver, Strating_Point, Rebate columns

And I have another dataset, I called 'transaction data' with Patient_Age column.

Now I like to pass this df2 (Patient_Age) via the 'Master Data' set and pick up all df1 values based on 'Starting_Point'....

Example: for 4 patient age = Starting point is 0 (because it is less than next starting point 20 and more than current starting point 0)

For Patinet_age 23 & 45 patient age = Strating_point is 20 (because both values are more or equal to currnet starting piont and less than next starting point)

For patinet_age 99 = Starting point is 50 (because 99 is more than equal to the currnet starting point 50 and there is no additional starting point in the Driver D1

```py
raw_data1 = {'Driver': ['D1','D1','D1'],'Strating_Point': [0,20,50], 'Rebate':[1,5,10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, columns = ['Driver','Strating_Point','Rebate'])
        
raw_data2 = {'Patient_Age': [4,23,45,99]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2, columns = ['Patient_Age'])
        
raw_data3 = {'Patient_Age': [4,23,45,99], 'Driver': ['D1','D1','D1', 'D1'], 'Strating_Point': [0,20,20,50], 'Rebate':[1,5,5,10]}
desired_result = pd.DataFrame(raw_data3, columns = ['Patient_Age', 'Driver','Strating_Point','Rebate'])
    
        
df1.head()
df2.head()
desired_result.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
raw_data1 = {'Driver': ['D1','D1','D1'],'Strating_Point': [0,20,50], 'Rebate':[1,5,10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, columns = ['Driver','Strating_Point','Rebate'])

raw_data2 = {'Patient_Age': [4,23,45,99]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2, columns = ['Patient_Age'])
    
raw_data3 = {'Patient_Age': [4,23,45,99], 'Driver': ['D1','D1','D1', 'D1'], 'Strating_Point': [0,20,20,50], 'Rebate':[1,5,5,10]}
desired_result = pd.DataFrame(raw_data3, columns = ['Patient_Age', 'Driver','Strating_Point','Rebate'])

#solution
df2['Strating_Point'] = pd.cut(df2['Patient_Age'], [0, 20, 50, 100]).apply(lambda x: x.left)
df2.merge(df1, right_on = 'Strating_Point', left_on = 'Strating_Point')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In 1st solution line, is there I can call table field instead of hard coding values " [0, 20, 50, 100])" please?    df2['Strating_Point'] = pd.cut(df2['Patient_Age'], [0, 20, 50, 100]).apply(lambda x: x.left)

Comment: I tried via below code. But my result is missing last line

Comment: df2['Strating_Point'] = pd.cut(df2['Patient_Age'], df1['Strating_Point']).apply(lambda x: x.left)
result1 = df2.merge(df1, right_on = 'Strating_Point', left_on = 'Strating_Point')

Comment: You can do that, but you need to add a large value to the end of that. For example you can use to_list to convert the Strating_Point column to a list then append a large value to that and then use that for cutting.